# Sort spreadsheet by column containing IP addresses (one IP address per cell)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, ip-address, google-sheets-formula

Using the default sorting engine, the following list is considered sorted:

```
10.0.0.219
10.0.0.22
10.0.0.223
```

This is incorrect.  The sorting should be:

```
10.0.0.22
10.0.0.219
10.0.0.223
```

It is not safe to assume the first three octets will be static.  For instance, other IP addresses include:

```
10.35.10.11
10.28.66.30
```

Comment: Are you okay with macro?

Comment: Will there always be the same number of digits in the first three sections?

Comment: No, there will not always be the same number of digits in the first three sections.  I will add other examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realize this is an old post, but in the interest of providing a working solution, I present the following.

Just put this formula in an adjacent cell and update the references to point to the cell containing your IP address (A1 in this example). This will produce a result similar to 010.121.008.030, which can then be sorted (correctly) alphabetically. Then set the column width to zero and voila. Time to enjoy a cup of coffee.

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,1,FIND(".",A1)),"000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-1-FIND(".",A1)),"000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1)-1-FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)),"000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1)+1,LEN(A1)),"000")
```

Answer (score 4):

There's several ways to do this, not sure if this is for more permanent use or just a one off.

1. Text to Columns

   > You can split the IP address into columns and sort the data as a table using an advance sort.
2. Sort

   > Using the built in sorter, you can create a custom sort order.  If you are just doing addresses in the same octet (e.g. 10.0.0.x) then you can add 10.0.0. as your order and it will do a numeric sort on the left overs.  This is probably not as intended, but then again it works.
3. Hidden Column

   > Google suggests several answers involving an additional column where you break out the IP address as a numeric value and then sort on that column.
4. VBA

   > Could do this all in VBA and slurp all the data up into memory and rewrite the list.  Advantage here would be the ability to reuse and extend.

Comment: which route did you go down in the finish?